# Active Directory Group in Local Administrators Group on server - Access denied

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have added an AD group with a user as a member into the Local Administrators Group on a server.

When running a Remote PowerShell script I am getting an Access Denied error, but if I add the AD user directly into the Local Administrator Group the Remote PowerShell Script works fine.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

thanks
Håkan

Comment: This is off topic for [so] as it's not a direct issue with your code, voting to move to [sf] where software issues like this are better suited.

Comment: I agree it belongs on Server Fault. But things to check: 1. The group is a security group (not distribution). 2. If the group is on a different domain than the server is joined to, the group should be universal (as long as the two domains are in the same AD forest)